# How to perform an action on a C# application after pressing an Arduino button?

Tags: c#, c++, arduino

I am doing a school project where it would be nice to perform actions in a c# application by pressing physical Arduino buttons.

I have seen plenty of tutorials on how to perform actions in Arduino by pressing buttons in c#, but none of this reversed. I only saw somewhere that I needed to add a "serial port listener" but it wasn't explained and I don't know this term.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: just do any tutorial on serial communication for Arduino and any one for C#. Then let them communicate. the Arduino will send some value through it's serial interface and your C# application will listen on the port your Arduino is connected to.

Answer (score 2):

You can write a C# (.net) program that listens/writes to the serial port the arduino is connected on
[Microsoft's page on how to write data from a .form application to a serial device](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.write?view=netframework-4.8)

The arduino can read incomming serial data periodicaly using the following example:
[Arduino code on how to "listen" to a serial port](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/SoftwareSerialRead)

This is just a starting point..

**edit: I now see you are asking for the "from arduino to PC" button interaction!**

Just send a character over the serial port from your arduino: 
[send a character over serial with arduino](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/write/)

Receive the character in your windows application:
[read a character in a .net application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.readchar?view=netframework-4.8#System_IO_Ports_SerialPort_ReadChar)